# object instance confusion in python

Tags: python, oop, object, instance

Hi I am trying to manipulate csv file as below

```
import csv
data=csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb'))
a= [row for row in data]
print a
```

The output of the code is (comma spearated rows--> in list format):

```
 [['aaaaa', '1234234'], ['bbbb', '2343536'], ['cccc', '5675675'], ['dddd', '2344234'],    ['eeee', '5435324'], ['fffffff', '4353442']]
```

I will get null value when I use

```
print [row for row in data]
```

I will be helped to have views to this confusion. Thank You

Comment: Works for me, cannot reproduce problem.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader` returns an iterator which is good for only one pass through the data. You are probably trying to iterate through `data` twice; the second time, there is no content left in the interator, so

```
print [row for row in data]
```

prints an empty list.

If you want to iterate through `data` more than once, and have enough memory, you could convert `data` to a list:

```
data = list(csv.reader(open('data.csv', 'rb')))
```

If you don't have enough memory, you would have to parse the CSV again.

Comment: I meant when i dont assign variable `a` to get data and instead print directly as `print [row for row in data] ` I get null.

Comment: Run your code as a script from the terminal. Do not use an IDE or an interactive session. Do you still see the problem?